# Grab all string start and end with character php

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have this string

```
"%John%" abxcca - "%Cameron%" , "%Warner%-%Bros%"
```

I want to extract list of word enclosed withh `%`  character
result expected is : `[ 'John','Cameron','Warner','Bros']`

How can I accomplish in PHP by regex?

I tried with `(\%.*\%)+`

but it only get from 1st % to last `%` , it can not seperate

Comment: Try out some regex using online tools like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) then come back with some attempted regular expressions.

Comment: Where are you having issues? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sorry ,. I updated the try before

Answer (score 1):

I did some regex learning right now and this seemed to work...

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/%(.*)%/U', '"%John%" abxcca - "%Cameron%" , "%Warner%-%Bros%"', $matches);


array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '%John%',
    1 => '%Cameron%',
    2 => '%Warner%',
    3 => '%Bros%',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'John',
    1 => 'Cameron',
    2 => 'Warner',
    3 => 'Bros',
  ),
)
```

IDK if this is the best way though, regex noob myself.

Answer (score 1):

I got it :).....................

```
%(.*?)%
```